# Hardcode value of column name and column in select query with pipe delimiter

Tags: oracle, select, hardcoded

I want to hard-code a column name and its value as `New York` in a select query with pipe delimiter. E.g. `Emp` table has columns `EmpId`, `EmpName`, `Salary`. I want output such as

```
Select EmpId ||'|'||
       EmpName ||'|'||
       'NewYork' as City  ||'|'||
       Salary
 from Emp
```

Here I want `City` column in output query and its value should be `'NewYork'` for each record.

Here I am getting error as `"FROM keyword not found where expected"`. When I use comma instead of Pipe Delimiter I am getting result but not with Pipe. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alias `as City` is in wrong place, remove it. You can alias only the final result of the concatenation. So you should put an alias after the `Salary` and `Salary` only in your case.

Comment: Comma is used to separate column names or expressions in the SELECT list from one another. A pipe, on the other hand, is used to concatenate strings/columns and return a single value/column. E.g. `SELECT a, b FROM tableX` would give two columns - `a` and `b`; whereas `SELECT a || b FROM tableX` would give a single column that is the concatenation of values in columns `a` and `b`. What exactly do you want here?

Answer (score 2):

```
with emps as (
  select 1 as id, 'Smith' as name, 2000 as salary from dual
  union
  select 2, 'Jones', 2200 from dual
)
select
  id || '|' || name as record1,
  id || '|' || name || '|NewYork|' || salary as record2,
  'NewYork' as city
from emps;
```